# Search for whole words in the Text widget with the search method

Tags: regex, search, python-3.x, text, tkinter

I am trying to find a way to match whole words using the Tkinter `Text` *search* method, but I have not found a consistent way of doing it. I have tried to set `regexp` to `True` and then use word boundaries of the `Tcl` regular expressions, with `\y` wrapping the word:

```
pos = text_widget.search('\\y' + some_word +'\\y', start, regexp=True)
```

It seems to work, but I think there might exist another way of doing it.

Comment: If it seems to work, why do you need another way? What attribute will this other way have that will make it better?

Comment: @BryanOakley I thought there was a simpler way to do it, like setting a parameter `all=True`, but I might be getting crazy

Comment: @Rinzler, what do you mean by "whole words". Do you just want to find something like `r"\w+"`?

Comment: @noahbkim I mean for example `are` in "How `are`
 you?" instead of `are` in "What did you `prepare`"?

Comment: @Rinzler Just develop your regular expression. For as many cases as I can think of off the top of my head, you could just use something like `r"\bare\b"`.

Comment: @noahbkim Yes, that's exactly what I did. At the beginning, I was doing it with the `Text` widget builtin `search` method, but I then decided to create my own searches methods, with Python regular expressions instead of tcl/tk ones (like in my above example).

Comment: @noahbkim, just a head's up: in Tcl (at least as of version 8.5), the regular expression example that you typed would be `r"\yare\y"` instead of `r"\bare\b"` because in Tcl the `\b` matches a backspace character.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a snippet of code that will allow you to search for any regular expression in the text widget by using the [tcl character indexing syntax](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm):

```
import tkinter
import re

root = tkinter.Tk()

text = tkinter.Text(root)
text.pack()

def findall(pattern, start="1.0", end="end"):
    start = text.index(start)
    end = text.index(end)
    string = text.get(start, end)

    indices = []
    if string:
        last_match_end = "1.0"
        matches = re.finditer(pattern, string)
        for match in matches:
            match_start = text.index("%s+%dc" % (start, match.start()))
            match_end = text.index("%s+%dc" % (start, match.end()))
            indices.append((match_start, match_end))
    print(indices)

    root.after(200, findall, pattern)

root.after(200, findall, r"\w+")
```

However, if you are dependent on the tkinter.Text.search function, I believe the `idlelib EditorWindow` class uses it to do its syntax highlighting.

Comment: This solution won't work if your text editor has embedded widgets or images.

Comment: @BryanOakley, do you have another way to solve for that then? I've never really had to deal with embedded objects.

Comment: The solution is just to use the built-in search feature. There's nothing your solution does that it can't do.