# Is there a way to make .search in tkinter not find words within words?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a program which highlights certain words in the text widget as the user writes them.

Everything is working so far except that the program keeps highlighting words within words, and I don't know how to make it not do that.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

textbox = Text(frame,width=100, height=10)
textbox.grid(row=1, column=7, columnspan=10)

textbox.tag_config("vegetables", foreground='green')
textbox.tag_config("fruits", foreground='red')

def search(textbox, keyword, tag):
    pos = '1.0'
    while True:
        idx = textbox.search(keyword, pos, END, nocase=True)
        if not idx:
            break
        pos = '{}+{}c'.format(idx, len(keyword))
        textbox.tag_add(tag, idx, pos)


def search2(event):
    for word in vegetables:
        search(textbox, word, "vegetables")
    for word in fruits:
        search(textbox, ordet, "fruits")

textbox.bind("<space>", search2)

frame.mainloop()
```

I'm using "vegetables" and "fruits" as examples here to make the function of the program more intuitive.

The problem I'm trying to fix can be illustrated by the following sentence, which shows how the program identifies a vegetable within another word which means something else:

"All I want is **pea**ce on earth"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `\y` to match word boundaries.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310464/search-for-whole-words-in-the-text-widget-with-the-search-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `regexp=True` option and use `\y` to match word boundaries.

```
def search(textbox, keyword, tag):
    pos = '1.0'
    while True:
        idx = textbox.search(fr'\y{keyword}\y', pos, END, nocase=True, regexp=True)
        if not idx:
            break
        pos = '{}+{}c'.format(idx, len(keyword))
        textbox.tag_add(tag, idx, pos)
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? It won't work. The text widget `search` method doesn't use regular expressions by default.

Comment: I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310464/search-for-whole-words-in-the-text-widget-with-the-search-method) that it does work.

Comment: Needed the `regexp=True` option.